# Input in python not recognized

Tags: python, function, input

I was adding an input function in one of my python programs an hour ago, and using:

```
location = input()
```

I got this extremely annoying error message which I do not understand: "hi" is not recognised. PS. "hi is what i wrote in the input box".

I don't get why input() is no longer working. It should be working the exact same way as it did before. I went into my main python folder and tried to run another program from a while ago that had an input in it, and got the same result - all programs with input() in it worked before! Just why dosen't python recognise what the input function is anymore?? Its really strange.

I have scoured the internet for an answer, and with no result, I have come to stack overflow for help.

Meanwhile, I can do absolutely nothing about it. I am SO confused right now.

Comment: which Python version are you using ?

Comment: use raw_input in python 2 and input in python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mehdi Pourfar stated, you should use `raw_input` in python2 and `input` in python3.

python2

```
> help(input)
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

python3

```
> help(input)
input(prompt=None, /)
    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    ...
```

Example of `input` in python2

```
>>> def foo(): print('foo called')
... 
>>> input('> ')
> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>> input('> ')
> foo
<function foo at 0x7f24ff7ee6e0>
>>> input('> ')
> foo()
foo called
```

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, it turns out I didn't know what version I was using. For some reason, I accidentally switched back to 2.7 which is not what I normally use (I have both versions) and therefore the input function was different. I will continue using 3.1 thx